# SQL Server 2012 Running version 9.0.1399 instead of 11.0.****

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have sql server 2008 running on my machine for a  pretty long time now. I recently installed  2012 on the same system without problems. But on starting the software, I got a prompt saying I can import the sql server 2008 settings to sql server 2012, for which I mistakenly selected Yes instead of No. Now sql server 2012 is running 9.0.1339 version (version of 2008) instead of the one that comes with 2012. I uninstalled 2012 and installed again hoping that it will return to the default settings but it didn't work.

Please I need help in resolving this issue.

Many thanks.

Comment: What component(s) are you finding have that version? From what you've described so far, it should be just SSMS. And even there, I suspect that you're just running the wrong one (i.e. you have both 2008 and 2012 SSMS installed and are running 2008).

Answer (score 0):

I think , this will help you.
First close your management studio.
go to your use folder (in win 7/8, C:\Users\username)

From that open "Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Settings"
In that you will find some files, move it to other folder.
Now, open management studio again.

Comment: Thanks Harsh, but it didn't work. I did exactly as you said but it still running the version 9.0. Another thing I discovered was after opening SQL Server Configuration, I noticed the SQL server services running in Sql Server 2008 is the exact one I found for 2012. I hope this gives a lead as to what the solution will be. Thanks.